# Firebase JSON Location in Console

Tags: ios, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an iOS app using JSON and the console for Firebase. I have set up everything for Firebase in the console but was also referring to this Ray Wenderlich document for help (and it has been very useful).

https://www.raywenderlich.com/3-firebase-tutorial-getting-started

My question is regarding the Structuring Data section. In particular, the JSON they refer to for the data model is:

```
// The root of the tree
{
  // grocery-items
  "grocery-items": {

    // grocery-items/milk
    "milk": {

      // grocery-items/milk/name
      "name": "Milk",

      // grocery-items/milk/addedByUser
      "addedByUser": "David"
    },

    "pizza": {
      "name": "Pizza",
      "addedByUser": "Alice"
    },
  }
}
```

My question is - where is this file stored or created or what would it typically be called? I need to set up a different version of this JSON for my app (i.e. it doesn't involve Grocery items, but it does involve users uploading photos).

I was unable to locate the JSON in the project files and so was trying to follow this example for my own project and couldn't figure out where this JSON file or data is stored. Where in Xcode is it, or is it in the console somewhere?

Comment: If you're trying to import JSON into Realtime Database, you can use whatever file you want and store it wherever you want.

Comment: OK - say my model for my app involves users and photos. Do I just create my own JSON (similar to the above grocery list JSON for a grocery item app) and upload it to the console (or wherever) and just refer to that file wherever its stored?

Comment: Once you import data, you won't use the JSON file again.  You will access the database directly.

Comment: Ok  - so in the tutorial it states: "No matter how it’s formatted on the client, all data stored in Firebase is JSON." Does this mean I don't actually explicitly do anything regarding JSON and that Firebase handles all of the JSON related parts of the data? I just create my model with users and photos and then set up my project so it works with Firebase (i.e. uploading photos via the console, etc) and the JSON stuff is just what's going on with Firebase internally?

Comment: JSON is the internal structure as well.

Comment: Ok - so I just want to clarify - I don't do anything myself inolving JSON or creating any JSON files with my data or model.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking now.  If you're confused by the tutorial, I'd reach out to the creator of that content.

Comment: I think I understand the issues. If I reword my question: When setting up a Firebase Database for my app and using it for creating my app, do I myself actually need to create a JSON file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no requirement to work with a JSON file when dealing with Realtime Database.  You can read and write the data directly with a provided SDK.  JSON file import is provided as a convenience to bootstrap the initial contents of your database, or restore a backup saved from the console.

Comment: Ok awesome. This answered my question (although your comments pretty much did as well, but I wanted to double check and confirm my understanding of this point).